# Site Definition with Document library by default

Tags: 2010, document-library, site-definition

I've created a new Site Definition which does not use Publishing features and I need to have 5 document libraries created by default on the new site created using this Site definition.

The Collab. Team feature gets activated, so I am able to manually create these libraries after a site is created using this Site Definition, however I'm looking for an automated way of doing it.

Is it something I can do through the ONet.xml or do I have to use features with modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself by experimenting a little.

In the ONet.xml file in the `<Lists>` note create a new `<List>` note with the following:

```
<List FeatureId="00bfea71-e717-4e80-aa17-d0c71b360101" 
      Type="101" 
      Title="My Magical Document Library"
      Url="/MagicalDocLib"
      QuickLaunchUrl="/MagicalDocLib/AllItems.aspx" />
```

- [FeatureId & Type references](http://blogs.technet.com/b/vinitt/archive/2009/11/04/list-of-feature-id-listtemplate.aspx)
- [Site Definition tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg276356.aspx)

Comment: Yepp, this is a way to do it with Site Definitions :) Just a question out of curiosity, is there a reason why you are still using Site Definitions over Web Templates?

Comment: @RobertLindgren My teammembers have decided to use Site Definitions instead as the needs of the client are very strict and the templates are not to be updated. So the flexibility of the Web Template is not a necessity and it's an on-premise installation.

Comment: Fair enough :) Although it will give you a more complex upgrade process when moving to new SP versions!

Comment: @RobertLindgren I agree. Hopefully the upgrade won't be my task!

Comment: Care to explain the downvote?